# Is it possible to distinct a PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event on a WPF DataGrid, whether it came from the grid directly, or a cell item?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` containing a few checkbox columns, textbox columns and combobox  columns. I have implemented the functionality to drag and drop rows of the grid, mostly according to [this guide by Philipp Sumi](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/moving-data-grid-rows-using-drag-and-drop).

As he states in the blog there are some registration issues using the `MouseLeftButtonDown`Event to start dragging the row. In my case for example it works only if the row was selected beforehand, therefore needing two clicks to start to drag a row. This is why I used the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`event, which is - as I understand - a tunneling event that also fires on the cell items.

Here is my question: in the eventhandler I want to distinguish between it beeing fired on a cell item (checkbox, combobox,..) or the datagrid directly since I want to cancel the drag functionality in case for example the user clicked on a combobox. My initial idea was to use `MouseButtonEventArgs.OriginalSource` for this, but this seems to be a `Border` for several items as well as the datagrid itself.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this? Otherwise, my next idea would be to use `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events on all items and set a flag there.

Comment: The idea in the last sentence came while writing the question, since I already use `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events to change the mouse cursor accordingly, however I am still curious if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: You might want to check the `OriginalSource` property of the `MouseEventArgs` in the event handler.